# Generating models gets longer and longer

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, keras

I use this function to generate keras models :

```
def nn_model(n1,n2=None,n3=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(n1, input_dim=len(features), init='he_normal'))
    model.add(PReLU())
    if n2 != None:
        model.add(Dense(n2, init = 'he_normal'))
        model.add(PReLU())
    if n3 != None:
        model.add(Dense(n3, init = 'he_normal'))
        model.add(PReLU())
    model.add(Dense(1, init='he_normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adadelta')
    return(model)
```

The code to run it :

```
N1 = [10,9,8,7,6]
N2 = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, None]
N3 = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, None]
test_list = [item for item in product(N1,N2,N3) if sorted(item, reverse = True) == list(item)][start_index:]
for m,(n1,n2,n3) in enumerate(test_list):
    model = nn_model(n1,n2,n3)
    # fit model and predict
```

It works fine, but each time I call it, it gets slower to return the compiled model. If I restart Python, I works again like normal, but after each iteration it become slower. After 30 iterations it took almost 5 minutes, against 10 seconds for the first call.
The models I run are similar in shape and size, so that is not the issue. If I generate the same model first or after 10 iterations, it will be much longer after 10 iterations.

Does anyone know where this may come from and how to avoid it (without restarting python every 5 iterations).
I run this in IPython, on a tensorflow backend on a GTX650Ti (1Go internal memory).
It is also worth noticing my RAM consumption slowly grow (~50-100Mo by call).

Comment: Not familiar with `keras`, however first thing that comes to mind is to maybe replace `return` with `yield` since a generator consumes far less memory and is active only when called upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All models are created in a default TF graph, which gets bigger over time.

The solution is to either create the models inside a graph scope, or to use the following Keras utility to clear the default graph:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
```

Comment: It gets bigger even if you overwrite it? (Like in my case I always overwrite the `model` variable)

Comment: Yes, because Keras uses an internal single default tf graph.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos what is the difference between using this `K.clear_session()` and the `del model` line that we see in the Keras documentation? Also, I would appreciate some clarification as of **when** and **where** that line should be used. It's unclear why and how the TF graph grows over time despite using the same model over and over again. Thanks! :)

Comment: Every time you apply a model, as in model(inputs), this rebuilds a forward graph.